# Question on the proof of completeness theorem

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

We want to prove the model existence lemma:  $\mathcal{\varGamma}$ is a consistent set of $\mathcal{L}$-sentences $\Leftrightarrow$ $\mathcal{\varGamma}$ has a model.

In the Henkin-style proof, we make a model $\mathcal{M}$ for $\mathcal{\varGamma}$ [By making a model for the maximal and Henkin $\mathcal{L_{\omega}}$-theory $T'$ that is extended over the $\mathcal{L}$-theory $T=${$A:\Gamma\vdash A$}]

$*$Hint: $\mathcal{L_{\omega}}$ is the extension of $\mathcal{L}$ by adding constants corresponding to the existensial formulas in $\mathcal{L}$ [Infinite union over recursively defined extentions of $\mathcal{L}$].

The process is well-known and I won't mention it in detail. Okay, surely it is a model for $\mathcal{\varGamma}$, But $\mathcal{M}$ is a $\mathcal{L_{\omega}}$-model.

Now, the question is: Weren't we supposed to find a $\mathcal{L}$-model for $\mathcal{\varGamma}$? If yes, then what's worthy about the $\mathcal{L_{\omega}}$-model $\mathcal{M}$? And if no, please clarify me about what's going on!

Thanks

Comment: Just throw away the interpretations of the added constants symbols (and function symbols if you are doing it that way).

Comment: I'm afraid I'm didn't the point of what you said dear André. Can you explain?

Comment: Well, maybe I am answering the wrong question. We can construct an $L_\omega$ model $M$ of $\Gamma$. This is not quite an $L$-model, since it has interpretations of the new constant symbols. But $M$ can be made into an $L$-structure $M_0$ by not interpreting the added constant symbols. All sentences of $\Gamma$ are true in $M_0$.

Comment: What you say is that for any $\mathcal{L}$-sentence $A$ in $\mathcal{\varGamma}$  we have $\mathcal{M_{0}}$$\vDash A$. Now suppose $\exists x B(x)$$\in$$\mathcal{\varGamma}$. Since $\mathcal{M}$$\vDash \exists x B(x)$, we have  $\mathcal{M}$$\vDash  B(c)$ for some $c\in M$; that $c^{*}\in \mathcal{L_{\omega}}$. Now how do we know that $c^{*}\in \mathcal{L}$ (and so $c\in M_{0}$)?

Comment: It probably is not in the language $L$. But that's irrelevant. As a different example, let $L'$ be the usual language of fields, and let $M$ be a field. Make a new structure $M_0$ by throwing away the interpretation of the multiplication symbol. Then $M_0$ is an abelian group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $M$ be an $L_\omega$-structure which is a model of $\Gamma$, and let $M_0$ be the  $L$-structure whose underlying set is the same as the underlying set of $M$, and such that the interpretations of the non-logical symbols of $L$ are the same as their interpretations in $M$.

All sentences of $\Gamma$ are true in $M_0$, so the $L$-structure $M_0$ is a model of $\Gamma$.

Comment: Oh yes the universe is fixed and  $\mathcal{L}$ doesn't  have to contain constants for all elements of that universe!

Comment: Let me know if I'm still wrong...

Comment: Yes,  the comment above is right,  Most $L$-strucures contain many elements that are not interpretations ofa term of $L$.